# Jquery Hover swapping two images in a li navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I have a site I built using Bootstrap.  I am putting an image on either side of each link in the navbar.  The navbar li a has a hover state through bootstrap/my personal css, and the links change color when you move the mouse anywhere near the link.  I put an img on either side of the link:

```
<li><a href="index.html"><img src="bonelefty.png"/>Home<img src="bonerighty.png"/></a>     
</li>

<li><a href="about.html" id="about"><img src="bonelefty.png" class="img- 
 swap"/>About<img src="bonerighty.png" class="img-swap"/></a></li>

<li><a href="rates.html"><img src="bonelefty.png"/>Rates<img src="bonerighty.png"/></a>  
</li>

<li><a href="contact.html"><img src="bonelefty.png"/>Contact<img src="bonerighty.png"/>   
</a></li>
```

I'd like to add some jquery like this, which I use elsewhere on my site

```
jQuery(function(){
    $(".img-swap").hover(function(){
        this.src = this.src.replace("bonerighty.png","bonerightw.png");
    },
    function(){
        this.src = this.src.replace("bonerightw.png","bonerighty.png");
    });
});
```

When I add the img-swap class to the image's next to the links they only change when you hover over that image, and only the one image changes (which makes sense to me). I cant figure out how to make both images change when the mouse gets close to the link and the link changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attack the LI to pull it:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("li").hover(function(){
        jQuery("img:first", this).attr("src","bonerightw.png");
        jQuery("img:last", this).attr("src","bonerighty.png");
    },
    function(){
        jQuery("img:first", this).attr("src","bonerightw.png");
        jQuery("img:last", this).attr("src","bonerightw.png");
    });
});
```

You can also do this with CSS:

```
li{
    background-image: url("bonerighty.png"), url("bonerightw.png");
    background-position: left center, right center;
}

li:hover{
    background-image: url("bonerightw.png"), url("bonerighty.png");

}
```

Comment: ok this did target the correct images and swap them, but the problem is now the right side image becomes the left side image boneleftw or bonelefty depending on whether it is currently highlighted.  ie it starts  correctly on both sides but then after the first mouse over boneright swaps to the boneleft and stays that way. then both bonelefty become boneleftw on further mouseover, hope that makes some sense.  Thanks so much.

Comment: now the left one becomes the right one. then after it has switched to the wrong side, doesnt react to further hovers and stays the bonerightw  very strange, thanks for all your help, please let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the class name, you should instead select the `a` tag or `li` tag. And use that to select your images. The result would be something like:

in your html

```
<ul class="img-swap">
<li><a href="link"><img>link<img></a></li>
</ul>
```

in your js

```
$('.img-swap li').hover(function(){
//select the images
});
```

or

```
$('.img-swap li a').hover(function(){
//select the images
});
```

here's a very rough example - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/cotAJ

Comment: tried it when I tried to implement for different images on each side of the link it stopped functioning completly (no hover effect on the images) not sure what i did wrong.

Comment: if all you are changing is the path to the images, then it should continue to work. I updated the code with different images...

Comment: any luck solving your problem?